# Differences between Javascript "export default" styles

Tags: javascript

Looking at JS (and particularly React) examples, I often see things like:

```js
function MyComponent () {
  //stuff
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Or with an arrow function:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  //stuff
}

export default MyComponent;
```

But I don't often see:

```js
export default function MyComponent() {
  //stuff
}
```

I know that the `const` version can't be reassigned, though I don't know that this is a meaningful concern or if it opens up optimizations.

I know that using arrow function syntax has some interesting differences from normal function syntax like not having a prototype, but I also know that decent JS implementations won't bother allocating the prototype unless something tries to use it.

So, is there a *technical* reason for one style over another here, or is it *just* a style issue?

Comment: The third one is actually the preferred one. The other two can cause hoisting issues with circular imports.

Comment: @Bergi aren't named function declaration hoisted too? I'm curious about the details in circular imports

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, they are, but `export default (…);` is not.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there aren't any performance difference between any of those and it's simply dependent on the coding style being enforced. some people like to declare all functions in one section of the code and exports in a seperate section to make it more organized.

although there is a difference between ES6 arrow functions `() => {}` and normal functions `function name() {}`
the `this` keyword context changes in both of them

in arrow function `this` refers to the object where it is defined and in normal functions it refers to the caller of the function.

one more advantage of using first and second style is that you can easily use named exports as well as default exports like this

```js
function myfunc() {};
const a = () => {};
const b = 12;

export default myfunc;
export { myfunc, a, b };
```

edit:

Also one more advantage between normal functions and arrow functions is that normal functions are hoisted, which means the function can be accessed anywhere within the file irrespective of where the function body is defined, however in arrow functions you cannot access it before initialization.

example:

```js
// works fine
export default a;

function a() {
    console.log("a");
}
```

```js
export default a;

// will throw error
const a = () => {
    console.log("a");
}
```

Comment: As Bergi noted, however, the hoisting can cause problems if the author of the module isn't careful about it.

Comment: @Pointy right you are, ultimately it comes down to the preference of the developer. but like you said the third option might be logically better

Answer (score -1):

An additional option is to co-locate your default export and other named exports all in a single statement at the end of the module. This can ease future refactoring so that modifications happen in one place in the module (instead of searching through the source code to find all instances of the `export` keyword):

```js
const foo = "hello";

const bar = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);

function logUpperCase(str) {
  console.log(str.toUpperCase());
}

export {
  bar,
  foo,
  logUpperCase,
  logUpperCase as default,
};
```

Here's a runnable example snippet:

```html
<script type="module">
// The following specifier is the code above, base64-encoded as a data URL:
import shout, { bar, foo } from "data:text/javascript;base64,Y29uc3QgZm9vID0gImhlbGxvIjsKCmNvbnN0IGJhciA9IE1hdGguY2VpbChNYXRoLnJhbmRvbSgpICogMTApOwoKZnVuY3Rpb24gbG9nVXBwZXJDYXNlKHN0cikgewogIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKHN0ci50b1VwcGVyQ2FzZSgpKTsKfQoKZXhwb3J0IHsKICBiYXIsCiAgZm9vLAogIGxvZ1VwcGVyQ2FzZSwKICBsb2dVcHBlckNhc2UgYXMgZGVmYXVsdCwKfTs=";

shout(foo); // logs "HELLO"
console.log(bar); // logs a random integer between 1 and 10 inclusive

</script>
```

[You can read more about Data URLs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)